# R::store does not work inside a model method [REDBEAN]

Tags: php, orm, redbean

I am trying to integrate REDBEAN into my web application.

I would like my model method to complete the "storing process" as well.

When I add

```
R::store($this)
```

in the last model-method it fails. How can I accomplish the same ?

Comment: Good question, i need this answer too:)

Comment: Take a look at my answer, found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the same question on the redbean google forum and got the answer.

https://groups.google.com/group/redbeanorm/browse_thread/thread/bcac973baabdd7bb

Comment: In short it is: 
R::store($this->bean)